# Dynamic display of receipt where it show all the products of a single vendor under its heading with total amount of that vendor's products

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

my system generates a receipt like the picture:

[image: my system generates a receipt like the picture]

I also have a list of manufacturers in my system
now I want to modify this receipt like this that the product should be under its manufacturer header which also show the total amount of products sold of that manufacturer in that order
[image]

The code of my receipt is here

```
 <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="item">QTY</th>
                                <th class="item">BON</th>
                                <th class="item">TOTAL QTY</th>
                                <th class="item">PRODUCT</th>
                                <th class="item">BATCH</th>
                                <th class="item">TRADE PRICE</th>
                                <th class="item">GST</th>
                                <th class="item">DISCOUNT</th>
                                <th class="item">TOTAL</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead> 
                        @foreach($order->orderItems as $item) 
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="item-list">{{$item->quantity}}</td>
                                <td class="item-list">{{$item->bonus_items}}</td>
                                <td class="item-list">{{$item->quantity + $item->bonus_items}}</td>
                                <td class="item-list">{{strtoupper($item->product->product_name)}}</td>
                                <td class="item-list">{{$item->product->batch_no}}</td>
                                <td class="item-list" colspan="2">{{$item->product->selling_price}}</td>
                                <td class="item-list"></td>
                                <td class="item-list">{{$item->product->selling_price *$item->quantity}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody> 
                        @endforeach
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr class="summary">
                            <?php
                                $f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
                                $words = $f->format($order->total_amount - $order->discount);
                                ?>
                                <td colspan="4">{{ ucwords($words.' Rupees') }}</td>
                                <td colspan="2"><strong>TOTAL: <strong>{{$order->total_amount}}</td>
                                <td colspan="2"><strong>DISCOUNT: <strong>{{ $order->discount }}</td>
                                <td><strong>TOTAL:<strong>Rs. {{$order->total_amount - $order->discount}}/-</td>



                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Is there any conditioning that I have to apply here or any function that I have to create in Model or Controller file.

Answer (score 0):

got a solution
first i have to edit the variable of orderController.php which is sending the data like this:

```
public function getInvoice($order){
    $order = Order::with('orderItems.product', 'salesmanRelation', 'orderBooker', 'clientRelation')->where('id', $order)->first();
    // dd($order);
    $orderItemsByVendor = [];
    foreach ($order->orderItems as $item) {
        if(isset($orderItemsByVendor[$item->product->company_name])) {
            array_push($orderItemsByVendor[$item->product->company_name]['items'], $item);
        } else {
            $total = 0;
            $company = $item->product->company_name;
            foreach($order->orderItems as $orderItem) {
                if($orderItem->product->company_name == $company) {
                    $total += $orderItem->quantity * $orderItem->product->selling_price;
                }
            }

            $orderItemsByVendor[$item->product->company_name] = ['items' => [$item], 'total' => $total];
        }
    }

    // dd($orderItemsByVendor);
    $data = ['order' => $order, 'items' => $orderItemsByVendor];
    return view('dashboard.invoice', compact('data'));
}
```

then i have to edit the invoice.blade.php file like this:

```
                            <tbody>
                        @foreach($data['items'] as $vendor => $item) 
                            @foreach($item['items'] as $orderItem)
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="item-list">{{$orderItem->quantity}}</td>
                                    <td class="item-list">{{$orderItem->bonus_items}}</td>
                                    <td class="item-list">{{$orderItem->quantity + $orderItem->bonus_items}}</td>
                                    <td class="item-list">{{strtoupper($orderItem->product->product_name)}}</td>
                                    <td class="item-list">{{$orderItem->product->batch_no}}</td>
                                    <td class="item-list" colspan="2">{{$orderItem->product->selling_price}}</td>
                                    <td class="item-list"></td>
                                    <td class="item-list">{{$orderItem->product->selling_price *$orderItem->quantity}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            <tr>
                                <td class="vendor-heading" colspan="8">{{$vendor}}</td>
                                <td class="vendor-heading">{{$item['total']}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
```

[and here is the required receipt fully working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNPgd.png)